# Store select list text in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a simple select form in cakephp populated from a table and want to store the text from the list instead of the index is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this like that:

```
<?php $list = $this->Model->find('list', array('Model.fieldForKey', 'Model.fieldForDisplay')); ?>
```

But are you sure that you want to? If two models (tables) are in a hasMany, belongsTo association, then storing an index is the proper way.

Comment: thanks a bunch. You are completely correct but its really a very small unnecessary feature and the indexes are not lining up right